# Pronoun endings in Akkusative Objects for "mein"

Tags: verb, sentence-structure, pronoun, accusative-and-infinitive

Consider the following sentence:

> Seit zwei Jahren tausche ich meine alten aber noch guten Sachen hier
>   und bin begeistert.

In this sentence, as per my understanding, we have a Akkusative Feminine object "Sachen". (https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Sache)
If this is true, then shouldn't the endings of adjectives be "-e" as in "alte" and "gute" as compared to "alten" and "guten".

What am I missing? Can any one please explain why my A2 book has placed "alten" and "guten" in this sentence?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Sache

Comment: You are missing that “Sachen” is plural. https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/mein

Comment: @DavidVogt, thanks for the link. So google translator was wrong as it claimed Sachen to be masculine.
If this is the case, then shouldn't the adjectives end with '-e' as in "alte" and "gute"?

Comment: @CarstenS yeah figured out that mistake. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Seit zwei Jahren tausche ich **meine** alten aber noch guten Sachen hier und bin begeistert.

**Mein** is a *Possessivartikel* and in this case it's **meine**, since it's

1. Accusative
2. Plural

That's because it refers to **Sachen** and they are Plural.

(Note that it would also be

> Seit zwei Jahren tausche ich **meine** Sache hier und bin begeistert.

Because *Sache* is feminine. See the [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Sache).)

Here is an [overview](http://longua.org/possessivartikel-ubersicht.php).

---

It's also *meine alten und guten Sachen*, because *Sachen* is

1. Feminine
2. Accusative
3. Plural

and has a

4. *Possessivartikel* (*meine*)

Here is an [overview](https://www.deutsch-lernen.com/03_Adjektivdeklination_II.htm).

Comment: According to my book, the ending for Akkusativ, Feminine and Plural is "-e". Is this wrong?

Comment: That was the rule, I didn't know about. Thanks man for your answer. It helped.